# How to prevent SCIP from doing restarts while solving MIPs

Tags: scip

I ma trying to solve an MIP and I noticed that sometimes scip restarts the problem again but the restarting does nothing. It spends a bunch of time trying find cuts and it doesn't find any.

The following is the message that comes before the restart is triggered. Is there a way to disable restarting?

```
Restart triggered after 50 consecutive estimations that the remaining tree will be large
(run 1, node 2309) performing user restart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable restarts by setting

```
estimation/restarts/restartpolicy = n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Leon. As an aside,  I was searching in the  6.0.1 documentation (which is what comes first when I googled for "SCIP parameters") and couldn't find this.

Comment: You should always look at the documentation of the SCIP version you are using ;). In-tree restarts (clairvoyant restarts they are called) were added in Version 7